# How does Linux TAR Exclusion works?

Tags: linux, relative-path, tar

Let's say I have a directory structure like this:

```
# tree original_directory/
|-- sub-1
|-- sub-2
|-- ignore_this_dir
|-- sub-3
```

Then the `tar` command to exclude the directory called `ignore_this_dir` is actually:

```
# tar -cf new_archived.tar original_directory/ --exclude=ignore_this_dir
```

OR

```
# tar -cf new_archived.tar original_directory/ --exclude=original_directory/ignore_this_dir
```

Answer (score 2):

The [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar) states:

> ```
> --exclude=PATTERN
>        exclude files, given as a PATTERN
> ```

Meaning

```
tar -cf new_archived.tar origin_directory/ --exclude=ignore_this_dir
```

will be ok in your situation as the pattern `ignore_this_dir` will match `original_directory/ignore_this_dir`.

Comment: Not really. When i do like that, the Directory is still included :S

Comment: What if you try `--exclude='*ignore_this_dir'` ?